# Limit keyboard input to specific characters with while loop and get()

Tags: matlab, user-input, matlab-figure

I am trying to limit the scope of possible inputs on a figure to 'y' and 'n' in a while loop in Matlab. However, the code below does not work as it (to my understanding at least) should.

```
answ = get(fig, 'CurrentCharacter');
while answ ~= 'n' & answ ~= 'y'
  answ = get(fig, 'CurrentCharacter');
end
```

How can I achieve the desired behavior? Only the first input seems to be caught by get. When I display the variable, the loop just goes on forever, even if the character in answ clearly is 'n' or 'y' and does not change with subsequent key presses. Additionally, sometimes the figure will disappear and the input will start getting caught by the terminal.
Executing the code in a command window seems to yield the desired behavior:

```
>> answ

answ = n

>> answ ~= 'n' & answ ~= 'y'

ans = 0

answ = x

>> answ ~= 'n' & answ ~= 'y'

ans = 1
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], with emphasis on "complete". This will make it easier for us to test your code, and make it more likely for you to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a loop to listen for characters, but use figure **Callbacks**!
For instance:

```
fig = figure('KeyPressFcn',@Key_Down);

function Key_Down(src,event)
    switch event.Character
        case 'y'
            disp('y')
        case 'n'
            disp('n')
    end
end
```

'KeyPressFcn' is an event raised when a key is pressed, and Matlab will call your `Key_Down` function. In the `event` structure you'll find the Key, the modifier (Shift, CTRL, etc) and other info.